# Save configurations in tails

Tags: configuration, tails, linux

I have tails installed in a pen drive (non in live mode but using the pen drive with a HDD) and I want to save the configuration. I read that I have that to use the "volume persistence", but I don't know as I have to configure it. Do you know the correct way to save the configuration on tails? I want to set, for example, the region and language, and also the keyboard language.

Thanks and regards, Kathy

Answer (score 2):

you cannot save the region, language and keyboard language in the encrypted persistence of tails. these settings always have to be set in the greeter. You can find a list of [persistence features in the tails documentation](https://tails.boum.org/doc/first_steps/persistence/configure/index.en.html#index3h1).

Comment: OK. I'll checkint it. Tkanks! Kathy

Comment: Hello again. Do you know if exist the possibility to configure and activate the features with the accesibility activated? I'm a blind, and I use a Screen Reader software "orca". I was to create a persistence volume with help of one person, but I need to know if I can to activate the persistence (since I saved the configuration with all features activated) but I cannot to change the language and region because I cannot to activate the use of the persistence in a welcome dialog.

Comment: I configured the persistence and language and region in the welcome dialog of tails with help of one person, but the configuration wasn't saved although I checked the option "Yes" use the persistence, and I entered my pass frase. There some option that I'm not considering? Thanks and regards, Kathy.